# How to change the content of Email templates in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

I have restricted the account creation to only bureaucrats. That is, only bureaucrats can create accounts for other users.

A confirmation email is sent to the newly created user on successful account creation in MediaWiki. But, would like to know where can i change the content of Confirmation Email template that i receive in MediaWiki.

Where can i find the various email templates used in MediaWiki?

```
  For eg: Content of Confirmation Email upon successful account creation is as below.

  Someone, probably you, from IP address ::1,has changed the email 
  address of the account "Admin" to this address on admin's Wiki!.

  To confirm that this account really does belong to you and reactivate
  email features on admin's Wiki!, open this link in your browser:
```

I would like to change the above content but couldn't find where these email contents are stored or from where it is invoked.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The email templates are stored as normal system messages, in the MediaWiki namespace, e.g. `MediaWiki:Notificationemail_body_changed`.

You can filter out all relevant system messages like this: [`Special:AllMessages&prefix=Notificationemail`](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3AAllMessages&prefix=Notificationemail&filter=all&lang=en&limit=50)

Currently, there are four:

- `MediaWiki:notificationemail_body_changed`
- `MediaWiki:notificationemail_body_removed`
- `MediaWiki:notificationemail_subject_changed`
- `MediaWiki:notificationemail_subject_removed`

Those pages will give you the message in your wiki's default language. To change a specific language (that a user might have chosen), use `MediaWiki:notificationemail_subject_removed/ar` (Arabic), `MediaWiki:notificationemail_subject_removed/en` (English), etc

Comment: It looks really great, but is there a way using which I can also shape email using HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 1):

@leo's answer is correct for messages sent regarding email authentication.

All other email messages as related to changes in pages, etc., are stored in system messages that start with `enotif_`, and you can see them all using this filter:
[`Special:AllMessages&prefix=enotif_`](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3AAllMessages&prefix=Enotif&filter=all&lang=en&limit=50).

**The messages for vanilla* MediaWiki are:**

- `enotif_impersonal_salutation`
- `enotif_subject_deleted`
- `enotif_subject_created`
- `enotif_subject_moved`
- `enotif_subject_restored`
- `enotif_subject_changed`
- `enotif_body_intro_deleted`
- `enotif_body_intro_created`
- `enotif_body_intro_moved`
- `enotif_body_intro_restored`
- `enotif_body_intro_changed`
- `enotif_lastvisited`
- `enotif_lastdiff`
- `enotif_anon_editor`
- `enotif_body`

And you can see them all using this filter:
[`Special:AllMessages&prefix=enotif_`](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3AAllMessages&prefix=Enotif&filter=all&lang=en&limit=50)

---

* People using [extension:Echo](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Echo) have a few other messages to change.